# How to store local private user data with React Native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm about to start working on a expense tracker app for mobile and I would like to use React Native with Expo (pretty new to mobile techs). Maybe I will share it with some friends or other people and the question that cames up is **where to store their data (in this case is sensitive as they will register their money's movement)**.

What I mean is, I could use any cloud DB (Mongo, Firestore, etc) but I will have access to everything they register there and I wouldn't like that, just for security and their privacy sake.

So, is there a way to store their data or everything they register locally in their phones? So the app can only access to the data that is stored there and I can't see it. Or any other possibility?

I found the [AsyncStorage API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/) but I don't know if this is the correct approach for what I'm looking for. I didn't code anything yet as I don't know which would be the right path.

Comment: Only if your app is totally offline then local == secret. You might consider encrypting data before storing it. Then it doesn't matter if data is persisted locally or remotely.

Comment: Didn't consider encrypting everything, it's really a good approach! But I would bet for something locally so I don't have to mantain a DB - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar case and i went for [realm.js](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) .

Comment: Hey there! Didn't know about realm! I read a bit of the docs after seeing your comment but how does it worked for you? Do you know if this is installed with the RN app? Also if the user removes the app it also removes the DB?

Comment: I don't see how this is providing secure storage?

Comment: See here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/advanced/encrypt/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Secure Store since you're using expo.

> expo-secure-store provides a way to encrypt and securely store key–value pairs locally on the device. Each Expo project has a separate storage system and has no access to the storage of other Expo projects.
> See https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

Comment: Hello! this is something similar to AsyncStorage right? Or which would be the difference? Do you know if it can scale properly? Asking because it says "Size limit for a value is 2048 bytes" so maybe it is no made for storing data as a DB...

Comment: It's not AsyncStorage since AsyncStorage is not encrypted. That's the main difference off the top of my head. Yes you should not use it to store large items like images.

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer! I think this is good a choice to keep in my mind but I will try RealmJs as Alvar said in another comment. If that doesn't work I will go with this one.